# Splitting a string with a space

Tags: java, string, split

I have a list of names (first and last).  I need find a way to split at the " " and ONLY print the last name to the console.  I have this currently, but, of course, it's still printing the first name.

```
for (int i=0; i<players.size(); i++)
{
  String s = players.get(i).toString();
  for(String token:s.split(" "))
    System.out.println(token);
```

Comment: Please specify the language you want to use... That's what tags are for.

Comment: Create the token array, then print the last element. That is assuming the last name has no spaces in it. Sorry, that is a terrible assumption.

Comment: And that the names are entered firstname lastname

Comment: @andrew I think that is the only thing that is "given".

Answer (score 2):

No need to use internal `for` loop. Change it as shown below.

```
for (int i=0; i<players.size(); i++)
{
    String s = players.get(i).toString();
    String [] token = s.split(" ");
    System.out.println(token[token.length -1]);    
}
```

Comment: Unless the name is Jack the Ripper. "Hello Mr. The!"

Comment: That won't work if a person has only one name (Cher, Prince, Elizabeth), nor will it work if the person has a double first name (Billy Ray Cyrus).

Comment: Yeah. It won't handle these cases. But going by what OP has posted I don't think he cares to handle these cases.

Comment: I can myself give to 10 cases in which this won't work. But has OP asked for a generalized solution ? He has clearly stated that the `input` would be `first_name` and `Last_name`. If you want to consider all the possible cases then this problem converges to extracting actual names from text which comes under category of `NLP`

Comment: "Only print the last name". It's not that hard... `println(token[token.length-1])` perhaps?

Comment: Depends on how the input is. I can tweak it to `Mr. Raj Aryan Sir`. It is common practice to add titles to the names. And it doesn't depend on this. More you deviate from the kind of input that can be provided  to the method more difficult this problem becomes. But your point is right I can at least edit my code to reflect your idea.

Comment: SO is meant to be a collaborative platform... Just doing my bit!

Comment: `if (token[token.length -1] != null)` this statement is not needed. if `null` than `System.out.println` will print null. Thanks.

Comment: @Trying While I agree that the statement is unnecessary, I disagree with your reason as to why.  The null-check is unnecessary because `split` doesn't return null array elements.

Comment: @spauken89 if it satisfies your requirement accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `String.split()` returns an array of tokens. Instead of iterating over the array and printing each one, store the array in a temporary variable (say `String[] tokens`) and just print the last one. (You can use `tokens.length` to find out how long the array is.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<players.size(); i++)
{
  String s = players.get(i).toString();
  String[] str=s.split(" ")
    System.out.println(str[str.length-1]);
}
```